# Convert list of single key dictionaries into a single dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of single-key dictionaries. For example:

```
lst = [
    {'1': 'A'},
    {'2': 'B'},
    {'3': 'C'}
]
```

I'd like to simply convert this into a normal dictionary:

```
dictionary = {
    '1': 'A',
    '2': 'B',
    '3': 'C'
}
```

What's the most concise/efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use reduce:

```
reduce(lambda r, d: r.update(d) or r, lst, {})
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [
...     {'1': 'A'},
...     {'2': 'B'},
...     {'3': 'C'}
... ]
>>> reduce(lambda r, d: r.update(d) or r, lst, {})
{'1': 'A', '3': 'C', '2': 'B'}
```

or you could chain the items calls (Python 2):

```
from itertools import chain, imap
from operator import methodcaller

dict(chain.from_iterable(imap(methodcaller('iteritems'), lst)))
```

Python 3 version:

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import methodcaller

dict(chain.from_iterable(map(methodcaller('items'), lst)))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, imap
>>> from operator import methodcaller
>>> 
>>> dict(chain.from_iterable(map(methodcaller('iteritems'), lst)))
{'1': 'A', '3': 'C', '2': 'B'}
```

Or use a dict comprehension:

```
{k: v for d in lst for k, v in d.iteritems()}
```

Demo:

```
>>> {k: v for d in lst for k, v in d.iteritems()}
{'1': 'A', '3': 'C', '2': 'B'}
```

Of the three, for the simple 3-dictionary input, the dict comprehension is fastest:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def d_reduce(lst):
...     reduce(lambda r, d: r.update(d) or r, lst, {})
... 
>>> def d_chain(lst):
...     dict(chain.from_iterable(imap(methodcaller('iteritems'), lst)))
... 
>>> def d_comp(lst):
...     {k: v for d in lst for k, v in d.iteritems()}
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('f(lst)', 'from __main__ import lst, d_reduce as f')
2.4552760124206543
>>> timeit.timeit('f(lst)', 'from __main__ import lst, d_chain as f')
3.9764280319213867
>>> timeit.timeit('f(lst)', 'from __main__ import lst, d_comp as f')
1.8335261344909668
```

When you *increase* the number of items in the inputlist to 1000, then the `chain` method catches up:

```
>>> import string, random
>>> lst = [{random.choice(string.printable): random.randrange(100)} for _ in range(1000)]
>>> timeit.timeit('f(lst)', 'from __main__ import lst, d_reduce as f', number=10000)
5.420135974884033
>>> timeit.timeit('f(lst)', 'from __main__ import lst, d_chain as f', number=10000)
3.464245080947876
>>> timeit.timeit('f(lst)', 'from __main__ import lst, d_comp as f', number=10000)
3.877490997314453
```

Increasing the input list further doesn't appear to matter from here on out; the `chain()` approach is a small percentage faster but never gains a clear advantage.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [dictionary comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> lst = [
...     {'1': 'A'},
...     {'2': 'B'},
...     {'3': 'C'}
... ]
>>> {k:v for x in lst for k,v in x.items()}
{'2': 'B', '3': 'C', '1': 'A'}
>>>
```

Comment: This solution works for python3, for python2 you should use x.iteritems()

Answer (score 1):

```
answer = {}
for d in L:
    answer.update(d)
```

**Output**:

```
>>> L = [
...     {'1': 'A'},
...     {'2': 'B'},
...     {'3': 'C'}
... ]
>>> answer = {}
>>> for d in L: answer.update(d)
... 
>>> answer
{'2': 'B', '3': 'C', '1': 'A'}
```

OR

```
answer = {k:v for d in L for k,v in d.items()}
```